# Scala function literals vs normal private method

Tags: scala, functional-programming

As Scala provides a way to write function literals, which one is quite recommended?

For example I want to a `flatMap` or `map` on some object, I need to pass a function from `f: A => B` or similar.

For this function, we can use both function literals and a private normal method(Java way) in the class?

Comment: I do not think there is an official recommendation. I haven't found one in http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/ or http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/. So it's up to your preference. Choose whichever makes the code easier to read in that particular case.

Comment: What advantage would using a private method have?

Comment: I'll typically use anonymous functions, *unless* it would lead to repeated code, or the anonymous function would be too complicated and degrade readability.

Comment: I'd use either a literal in place or define function somewhere else as a literal. There are cases when using methods makes sense, but not private ones: `List(1,2,3).map(2.0.*)`

Comment: @Bergi I think the advantage of private method is you don't need to put everything in the same method, which can make you have small method with clean code and better readability. Also, if the same piece of code shared by two methods, definitely private method looks better. How do you think?

Comment: @DanielDarabos thanks. You are right. This is what I am currently doing, for a expression with just one line or two lines I use function literals others use private method.

Answer (score 1):

Function literals are instances of the different function traits, and as such they have some methods defined on them (`andThen`, `compose`, `apply`, `toString`): [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function1)

Partial functions have even more methods: [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.PartialFunction)

In many cases, the compiler allows you to put methods in places that expect function literals, so more often than not there is no difference. Partially applying a method (e.g. `myMethod _`) even converts it to a function literal, so that's even less of a reason to think too much about this.

In the end, you should use function-literals whenever you need to treat functionality as data, and I don't see any reason why you would use them otherwise.

Comment: Technically `_` is not partial application: `def m(a: Int, b: Int)(c: Int) = ...` then try `m(_:Int, _:Int)(_:Int)` vs `m _`

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're saying? The latter is what I mean. This is of course partial application of the parameter lists, but parameter lists are just a part of Scala, so in my head only the latter is actually partial application. The first is changing the structure of the function fundamentally.

Comment: I'd say partial IMO means, well, partial. You can't partially apply without changing the structure. `m(1, _)(_)` can't save the structure, can it? So extending it to all arguments (what kind of _partial_ application is it?) we get the former case. The latter is called eta-expansion and does "preserve" the structure, if you consider kind of a currying on the fly and transforming it to a completely different object a "preservation" (no, multiple parameter lists is not currying). Just to be accurate.